# ColdFusion Coding Guideline? Where did it go?

Tags: coldfusion, coding-style

Anyone seen the ColdFusion Coding Guideline that Adobe had on their site?  It seems to have disappeared and I don't have a copy.

Comment: You're right, they don't seem to be where they used to be (http://livedocs.adobe.com/wtg/public/coding_standards/).  I just pinged the Adobe twitter account to see if this is an oversight.  Will reply back if I hear anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here it is on the ['wayback machine' web archive](http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20090330013324/http://livedocs.adobe.com/wtg/public/coding_standards/contents.html)